# advice needed on microserver hardware for small business github and CI services

Tags: github

Me and my friends are setting up a small indie company for gaming. I want to get a server to install github on for our private repos and then also install jenkins for continuous integration testing. When it comes to servers I have no idea about the hardware and wanted to make sure I knew what I was doing before spending money.

I have my eye on this http://www.amazon.co.uk/HP-G1610T-ProLiant-Micro-Server/dp/B00DDIC1DA

Now if I bought 2 WD red 1TB drives and configured them as raid1 could I use the above to install windows 7 on with github and Jenkins to achieve everything I wish to do? We have very little funds and the above is our financial limit.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reason to run your own server if you're that constrained funding-wise.  I'd look into Bitbucket or similar for a private git repo, and there are plenty of free-tier server offerings with Jenkins support (e.g., OpenShift).  If it were me, I'd save the money for something else.

Comment: Not sure how much help that is going to be as we write in C++ and it looks like OpenShift and the like is for web applications. Unless I am misunderstanding. Plus it will need to be on a windows server so the Jenkins msbuild plugin can build our software. Thanks